# WPF Datagrid Binding field

Tags: c#, wpf

I have such a class,

```
public class Class1
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    public List<BaseInfo> baseInfos { get; set; }
}
```

and a datagrid

```
<DataGrid
            hc:DataGridAttach.CanUnselectAllWithBlankArea="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
            HeadersVisibility="All"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Class1}"
            RowHeaderWidth="60">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

[image]

I can't actually do that
How should I do to baseInfos Set AutoGenerateColumns="True" Automatically generated Columns,
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemsSource binding should be a list and not a single class, and the IsSelected is expected to be a property inside BaseInfo and not something outside of it!!
Could not understand why you have `Class1` as it does not help in anything!!

so add `public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;` to the class BaseInfo. something like that:

```
public class BaseInfo {
     public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string SOMETHING { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: because Baseinfo in 3-tier architecture Model ,And Baseinfo changes frequently during maintenance,That's how I got the idea,I'll have to add this [NotMapped] so EF doesn't map this field,Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

`AutoGenerateColumns` property  will automatically create empty columns for you，

but if you want create new row ,You need to create a list of `Class1` and bind it to `ItemSource`

.cs:

```
    public List<Class1> ClassList
    {
        get
        {
            return classList?? (classList= new List<Class1>());
        }
        set
        {
            classList= value;
        }
    }
    List<Class1> classList;
```

add some items:

```
ClassList.Add(new Class1
                {
                    IsSelected = true,
                });
                ClassList.Add(new Class1
                {
                    IsSelected = true,
                });
```

xaml:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}">
</DataGrid>
```